# Finding the longest string in a 2d array in C

Tags: c

I wrote a function that finds the longest string in a 2d array, it works, partially. My problem is that it takes the first longest string that it finds without checking the other ones.

For example, the following list of strings:

> eke
>   em
>   ekeke
>   eme
>    e
>    ememeememe
>   emem
>    ekekee
>   eooeeeeefe
>    eede

My function catches "ekeke" (the third string from the list) as the longest instead of "ememeememe ".

Here is my function:

```
void length(char str[][MAX])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 1; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        if(strlen(str[i]) > strlen(str[i-1]))
        {
            if(strlen(str[i]) > strlen(str[i+1]))
            {
                printf("%s", str[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`LEN` is a constant, his value is 10.
`MAX` is a constant, his value is 50.
The strings are given by the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: For each string you only check its length versus the length of the previous string and the next string in the array. `ekeke` is longer than `em` (the previous) and longer than `eme` (the next) and is therefore printed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - I have no debugger

Comment: @Ma250 1. You don't need a debugger to debug. 2. You should probably have a debugger. They're basically essential.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - Wait, nevermind, got you wrong, I do have one, and yes, I have debugged it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only comparing the previous and next strings. You need to check the lengths of *all* the strings.

```
void length(char str[][MAX])
{
    size_t longest = strlen(str[0]);
    szie_t j = 0;

    for(size_t i = 1; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str[i]);
        if(longest < len)
        {
           longest = len;
           j = i;
        }
   }
   printf("%s", str[j]);
}
```

I am assuming you have at least 1 string and handle corner cases (if user inputs less than `LEN` strings etc -- depends on how you fill the `str` with strings).